# Python 3: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0001.0110010110010102e+22'

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I'm a beginner, so sorry if this is obvious.

I'm at a loss here. I've been trying to make an encryption/decryption program, but I keep getting this error. I'm aware that there are other questions on this issue, but I still can't resolve it.

**Encryptor**:

```
import binascii
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(text.encode(encoding, errors)), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return int2bytes(n).decode(encoding, errors)

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_string = '%x' % i
    n = len(hex_string)
    return binascii.unhexlify(hex_string.zfill(n + (n & 1)))

#ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM
algorithm = 61913299

#ASCII ----> NUMBERS
raw = input("Enter text to encrypt:")

binary = text_to_bits(raw)
binary = int(binary)
algorithm = int(algorithm)
encrypted = binary * algorithm
encrypted = str(encrypted)
print(encrypted)

print("Done")
```

**Decryptor:**

```
import sys
import time

def to_bin(string):
    res = ''
    for char in string:
        tmp = bin(ord(char))[2:]
        tmp = '%08d' %int(tmp)
        res += tmp
    return res

def to_str(string):
    res = ''
    for idx in range(len(string)/8):
        tmp = chr(int(string[idx*8:(idx+1)*8], 2))
        res += tmp
    return res

incorrectpasswords = 0
password=("password")
originpassword = password
x = 1
algorithm = 61913299

while x==1:
    passwordattempt =input("Enter Password:")
    if passwordattempt == password:
        print("Correct")
        x = 2

    if passwordattempt!= password:
        print("Incorrect")
        incorrectpasswords = incorrectpasswords + 1
    if incorrectpasswords > 2:
        if x == 1:
            print("Too many wrong attempts, please try again in one minute.")
            time.sleep(60)


encrypted = input("Enter numbers to unencrypt:")

encrypted = int(encrypted)

one = encrypted / algorithm
size = sys.getsizeof(one)
one = str(one).zfill(size + 1)
one = int(one)
unencrypted = to_str(one)

x = unencrypted
```

For the conversion between binary and text, and text and binary, I used some code I found online.

Comment: Does it say which line is the error on?

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro Yes, sorry. Line 49. 'one = int(one)'

Comment: the `/` or "true division" operator in Python 3 unlike in earlier Python versions returns a float even when called with `ints`. If it is approopriate for your algorithm you can use `//` or "floor division" instead which will return an `int` provided its inputs are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code is not working because:

```
one = encrypted / algorithm
```

generates a float

to turn your string back into a number you should apply

```
eval(one)
```

or

```
float(one)
```

instead of

```
int(one)
```

(You can also turn it into an int after applying float or eval)
alternatively you might be able to get it by using integer division `//` as opposed to `/` , which will make `one` the type `int` by flooring the decimal result of the divison, but I'm not sure if that is the behavior you are looking for

Example in python 3 shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> one = 15/25
>>> size = sys.getsizeof(one)
>>> one = str(one).zfill(size+1)
>>> one
'00000000000000000000000.6'
>>> type(one)
<class 'str'>
>>> one = eval(one)
>>> one
0.6
>>> type(one)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: did you do it after you turned it into a string? or did you do it before that?

Comment: It should be applied instead of `one = int(one)`

Comment: I've added the example behavior from the python shell above